# Encontrar posição de caractere em string e remove-la

Tags: php, string, replace

Tenho um problema complicado de se resolver, existem 3 tipos de variáveis que recebem dados via post exemplo:

```html
$mes = "08";
$mes = "10";
$mes = "12";
```

No caso 3 tipos diferentes de string, necessito que o 0 seja removido quando for a primeira ocorrência na string (for o caractere inicial) já tentei de diversas formas até dando explode na entrada de dados, mais isso afeta a todos os dados da entrada e não seria necessário pois essa validação só deve ocorrer do numero 01 ao 09 sobrando somente a unidade 1 a 9. De que forma posso fazer isso ?

Comment: str_replace('0', '',$mes); ?

Answer (score 5):

Não precisa usar uma função para remover o zero da primeira posição. Você pode fazer a tipagem usando [`int`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting).

```
$mes = "08"; // string(2) "08"
$mes = "10"; // string(2) "10"
$mes = "12"; // string(2) "12"

$mes = (int) "08"; // int(8)
$mes = (int) "10"; // int(10)
$mes = (int) "12"; // int(12)
```